# Filtering eloquent relationship many to many query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 
Users, Departments, Positions, table.

User belongs to many department
Department has many positions
User belongs to many positions

I want a query that would give a single department with list of users and their position in that department.

```
    $department = DepartmentView::with(['users.positions' => function($query) {
                        // do something?
                        }])->where('tag', $tag)
                        ->get();
```

I also get the department through tag, and not ID. **Position table does not have tag column**, only department ID.

--

I could make it work by defining static Id, however the problem is I get the department via tag.

```
public function getDepartmentByTag($tag) {
$departmentId = 1; FOR TESTING PURPOSE, IT WORKS
$department = DepartmentView::with(['users.positions' => function($query) use($departmentId) {
                            $query->whereHas('department', function($query) use($departmentId) {
                                $query->where('departmentId', $departmentId);
                            });
                        }])->where('tag', $tag)
                        ->get();
}
```

Comment: `DepartmentView::with('users.positions' )->where('tag', $tag)->get()` this should do the trick

Comment: That's how it was before, but it gives all the position of user in all the department he is in.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer in what table do you have the `tag` column?

Comment: it would be better if you provide relationship you have defined in your model

Comment: Alexey Mezenin, in Department table.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer then Sohel0415's query will work. It will filter departments by tag and will load all users and positions for the department.

Comment: No, as I said, it gives me all the positions the user currently has(including the position the user has in ANOTHER department). I want to only get the user position that is in the department.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer the relationship between departments and positions is many-to-many? Or each position belongs to a department?

Comment: Alexey, Department Has many Position.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer so, you have `department_id` in `positions` table? I've posted the code below, if it's position `belongsTo()` department and you've defined relationships correctly, this will work.

Comment: Yes, position have department id. Position belongsTo department.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to only get the user position that is in the department

```
DepartmentView::with(['users.positions' => function($q) use($tag) {
        $q->whereHas('department', function($q) use($tag) {
            $q->where('tag', $tag);
        });
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: It's giving me 0 result. Where di the departmentName come from?

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer it's just an example. Use `id` or `name` or `tag` or whatever you like. If you want to use `tag` to filter department, remove `->where('tag', $tag)` and change `$q->where('name', $departmentName);` to `$q->where('tag', $tag);`. Also, don't forget to update `use()` clauses.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer if you want to filter `users.postitions.department` by tag, use the updated code.

Comment: I can only get it to work by using departmentId(I tested by defining a static variable) instead of departmentName, but I don't know where will I get departmentId(since I filter the query via tag). Using tag doesn't work btw. (probably since position table does not have tag column?)

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer the code will look filter by `tag` which is in `departments` table.

Comment: It gives empty result.

Comment: @JonathanLightbringer well, make sure you have this data (users with positions in the department with tag = $tag). And double check all the relationships definitions.